# Error al hacer un spinner adapter personalizado en android

Tags: android, android-spinner

Hola intento hacer un spinner en android con un  adapter para un objeto CatalogoDetalle, para que al seleccionar la opción me devuelva el id de la opción.
Utilizo el siguiente código

```
public class CatalogoDetalle {
    
    private int cad_idcatalogo;
    private String cad_nombreCatalogo;
    private int cad_idopcion;
    ...
    }
```

En el activity incio el spinner con

```
 List<CatalogoDetalle> tomadoDe; //los valores los traigo de la bd
    ..

      ArrayAdapter catAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CatalogoDetalle>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, tomadoDe);

        mySpinner.setAdapter(catAdapter);
        mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Get the value selected by the user
                // e.g. to store it as a field or immediately call a method
                CatalogoDetalle opcion = (CatalogoDetalle) parent.getSelectedItem();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
```

Sin embargo no se está mostrando correctamente.

En la lista me pone:
com.example.compras.model.CatalogoDetalle que es el nombre del objeto.
Muestro pantallazo aquí
[https://ibb.co/LrRFZg4](http://%20https://ibb.co/LrRFZg4)

Espero puedan ayudarme a encontrar qué hice mal.

Comment: Si cambias esto: `ArrayAdapter catAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CatalogoDetalle>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, tomadoDe);` por esto: `ArrayAdapter<String> catAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, tomadoDe);` ¿Te funciona?

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, ya logré solucionarlo con otra pregunta en este mismo sitio. La compartiría pero ya la perdí

Answer (score 2):

Logré solucionarlo agregando en la creación del ArrayAdapter lo siguiente

```
 ArrayAdapter catAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CatalogoDetalle>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, tomadoDe) {


            // And the "magic" goes here
            // This is for the "passive" state of the spinner
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // I created a dynamic TextView here, but you can reference your own  custom layout for each spinner item
                TextView label = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                // Then you can get the current item using the values array (Users array) and the current position
                // You can NOW reference each method you has created in your bean object (User class)
                CatalogoDetalle item = getItem(position);
                label.setText(item.getCad_descripcionesp());
               

                // And finally return your dynamic (or custom) view for each spinner item
                return label;
            }

            // And here is when the "chooser" is popped up
            // Normally is the same view, but you can customize it if you want
            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                        ViewGroup parent) {
                TextView label = (TextView) super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                CatalogoDetalle item = getItem(position);
                label.setText(item.getCad_descripcionesp());

                return label;
            }
        };
```

Y funciona perfecto